# Current Ruby version is not included in current RVM list rubies

Tags: ruby, rvm

MacOS X 12.6, in the Terminal (zsh), type command `ruby -v` shows:

```
ruby 2.7.7p221 (2022-11-24 revision 168ec2b1e5) [x86_64-darwin21]
```

type `which ruby` shows:

```
/usr/local/opt/ruby@2.7/bin/ruby
```

But command `rvm list` has a result of totally different ruby version like this:

```
rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.3.0 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

I don't have any other ruby version managers.

I want to set ruby 2.7.7 version as the default version because current Terminal is using this version and let current RVM to recognize this ruby version so it could appear in the list of `rvm list` rubies.

What should I do?

---

Update:

I uninstalled this RVM (which is linked to ruby 2.3) using ruby 2.7's gem using this command:

```
gem uninstall -i ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0 rvm
```

The uninstallation is successful. Then I reinstalled it followed the instruction of the webpage https://rvm.io/rvm/install : First, install the GPG-key; Then, using this command to reinstall RVM:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

But unfortunately, The new RVM still has only one version of ruby which is 2.3.0.

---

Update:

I deleted RVM and tried every other ruby version managers like `rbenv` `ruby-install` `asdf-ruby`. All of them failed to download newer version of ruby with throwing the same error message like this:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to 
see invocation)
make[1]: *** [test/asn1_internal_test] Error 1
make: *** [build_sw] Error 2
```

The only way I could successfully download ruby (any version) to this MacOS is via Homebrew.

Comment: Your current ruby 2.7 was installed by Homebrew. And your RVM does not seem to be fully setup, as it would otherwise say that you are using the system ruby.  Make sure that you have followed https://rvm.io/rvm/install when installing RVM.

Comment: In general, to get solutions to RVM problems I suggest you seek help from [RVM support](https://rvm.io/support) rather SO members. I've seen many RVM questions on SO that go unanswered. By contrast, the volunteers who provide RVM support have likely seen your questions, or variants thereof, many times, and therefore can quickly provide spot-on answers.

Comment: And I'd recommend that you not use RVM and instead use [asdf-vm](https://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html). (but only after fully uninstalling RVM)